# Access DB Query in Visual Basic Form

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm seeking help on how to return more than one row in a query. For example if I want the entire contents of a column in access, I want to return all rows to a ListBox.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim theConnectionString As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        txtSQL.Clear()
        theResults.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        theConnectionString.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Marc Wilson\Documents\FiddleFuckDB.accdb"
        theConnectionString.Open()
        Dim theDataSet As New DataSet
        Dim theDataTable As New DataTable
        theDataSet.Tables.Add(theDataTable)
        Dim theDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

        Dim theSQLStatement As String
        Dim theDBCommand As New OleDbCommand
        theSQLStatement = txtSQL.Text


        Try
            theDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [City] FROM PI", theConnectionString)
            theDataAdapter.Fill(theDataTable)
            Dim theRowCount As Integer = theDataTable.Rows.Count
            Dim theItemCount As Integer = theDataTable.Columns.Count
            MessageBox.Show("Row Count: " & theRowCount & vbNewLine & "Item Count: " & theItemCount, "Your Results...")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        Try
            theDBCommand = New OleDbCommand(theSQLStatement, theConnectionString)
            theResults.Items.Add(theDataTable.Rows(0).Item(0))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        theConnectionString.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The SQL Statement I'm using is `SELECT [City] FROM PI` (I have 3 rows of data and 4 different columns) I believe my mistake resides in this portion          `theResults.Items.Add(theDataTable.Rows(0).Item(0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ........

```
Dim x as Integer

Try

   theDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [City] FROM PI", theConnectionString)
   theDataAdapter.Fill(theDataTable)

   For x = 0 to theDataTable.Rows.Count -1
      theResults.Items.Add(theDataTable.Rows(x).Item(0))
   Next

Catch ex As Exception

   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

End Try
```

Comment: Tried it. It just returns Row 1 three times.

Comment: @mwilson : have you try this ? .. any comment ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the sql statement from `txtSQL.Text` that you are attempting to use.

A simple `SELECT` statement will retrieve all rows from a table, unless a `WHERE` clause is used to restrict the number of rows returned.

Comment: I'm sorry. The SQL Statement I'm using is "SELECT [City] FROM PI"

(I have 3 rows of data and 4 different columns)